# How to fix my on hover effect to highlight selected item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying highlight an item on hover and at the same time lower the "brightness" of the other items, so there is a focus on the on hover item. My item is made of a picture, a size selector and an add to cart button. What I want is for these three parts to highlight at the same time when the mouse is over any of those parts. I wanted to do this with CSS only and managed to get what I want kinda working, except if the mouse hovers the add to cart button or the selector, only those items will highlight. This is my CSS:

```
   #Productlist {
      list-style-type: none;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .Product img {
      width: 350px; 
      height: 400px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      left: 50px;
      margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .Product:hover img {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    #Productlist:hover img{
      opacity: 0.5;
      -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
      transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    } 

    .Product button {
      background-color: #141516;
      position: relative;
      right: 134px;
      display: inline-block;
      z-index: 1;
      padding: 15px 45px;
      line-height: 1.8;
      text-align:center;
      text-transform:uppercase;
      font-size:0.8rem;
      font-weight:600;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      border: 3px solid white;
    }

    .Product button a {

      position:relative;
      padding:0px;
      text-align:center;
      text-transform:uppercase;
      color:#888888;
      font-size:0.8rem;
      font-weight:600;
      line-height:60px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s;

    }

    .Product button:hover a {

      color:red;
      z-index: 1000;
    }

    .Product button:hover {

      color:black;
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid white;
    }

    #size{
      display: inline-block;
      z-index: 1;
      color: white;
      position: relative;
      right: 484px;
      border: 3px solid white;
      width: 120px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background: #141516 url("img/icon-select.png") no-repeat 90% 50%;
    }

    #size:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
```

This is my HTML:

```
    <div className='Webshop' id='Webshop'>
        <li id="Productlist">
            <div className='Product'>
              <img src={Seltzshirt}></img>
              <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="addit">Add to cart</button>
              <select id="size" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                <option value="large">Large</option>
                <option value="x-large">X-large</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className='Product'>  
              <img src={Seltzshirt}></img>
              <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="addit">Add to cart</button>
              <select id="size" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                <option value="large">Large</option>
                <option value="x-large">X-large</option>
              </select>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
```

**Update**

I updated my CSS and HTML to show some changes I made and applying Michael Coker's suggestion. Now when I hover an image, button, or selector, all images dim and both selector and button stay highlighted. Why is my `.Product img` ignoring to change `opacity: 1;` on hover?

I made this CodePen to show what my issue is: https://codepen.io/Feners4/pen/xdQmyQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the opacity of all images using `#Productlist:hover img { opacity: .5; }`, and exclude the current one with `#Product:hover img { opacity: 1; }`

```css
#Productlist {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#Product img {
  width: 350px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#Productlist:hover img {
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

#Product:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
}

#Webshop button {
  background-color: #141516;
  position: relative;
  right: 134px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 15px 45px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

#Webshop button a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #888888;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#Webshop button:hover a {
  color: red;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#Webshop button:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#size {
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  right: 484px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #141516 url("img/icon-select.png") no-repeat 90% 50%;
}

#size:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div className='Webshop' id='Webshop'>
  <li id="Productlist">
    <div id='Product'>
      <img src=http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png></img>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="addit">Add to cart</button>
      <select id="size" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                <option value="large">Large</option>
                <option value="x-large">X-large</option>
              </select>
    </div>
    <div id='Product'>
      <img src=http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png></img>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="addit">Add to cart</button>
      <select id="size" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                <option value="large">Large</option>
                <option value="x-large">X-large</option>
              </select>
    </div>
    <div id='Product'>
      <img src=http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png></img>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="addit">Add to cart</button>
      <select id="size" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                <option value="large">Large</option>
                <option value="x-large">X-large</option>
              </select>
    </div>
    <div id='Product'>
      <img src=http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png></img>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="addit">Add to cart</button>
      <select id="size" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                <option value="large">Large</option>
                <option value="x-large">X-large</option>
              </select>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble applying this method to my button and selector components. Using an `<li>` tag with them causes the button and selector to lose their placement and not be aligned the way I had them where the button and selector "are part" of the image frame.

Comment: After using your suggestion I've been trying to figure out why in my end the images are taken the whole page..

Comment: I still haven't figured out why the images are taking the whole screen. My CSS assigns them a size..Any ideas what might be happening?I'm using React btw..idk if this has to do anything with it..

Comment: @feners it's up to you to reproduce the behavior in your post, and we solve the question in the post. All I can do is guess at why it isn't working on your personal project, and that isn't productive for either of us.

Comment: I understand. I asked because the images where displaying with the correct dimensions before applying you code, so I was wondering what could have changed..

Comment: @feners if the problem in your post is solved, you should accept an answer, and if you're having trouble implementing in your project, make a new post.

Comment: Well as is with the images taking the whole screen..when I hover over one of the images (having only two images in my page), both dim so it is not working as is..thanks for the help though.

Comment: @feners like I said before, the point of stack overflow isn't for us to fix your personal site. It's your responsibility to reproduce the problem in your post, and we address the problem in your post. You have two answers here, both of which address the problem in your post. I used the html and css you shared and gave you a working example. If you can't implement it back on your project, how are we supposed to know why? You should make a new post about that. It very well could be a react problem which is beyond the scope of this post.

Comment: Hey man, mind seeing the Codepen I posted and checking why your code isn't working like it should on my end? Both images dim when I hover over them..

Comment: first, you're using `className` in your html. that will only work in your react environment. Second you have a specificity issue. You're using `#Productlist:hover img` to dim them both and `.Product:hover img` keep the one you're hoving from dimming, but `#Productlist:hover` is overwriting `.Product:hover` because `#Productlist` has higher specificity than `.Product`. You need to change `.Product:hover` to `#Productlist:hover` https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/QvzaLW

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, it cleared the doubt I had on what had higher specificity..

Answer (score 0):

Simple and basic explanation:

You need to target the hover of the parent like this and apply the style on all the childrens. After, apply `opacity: 1` on the current hovered element:

```
ul {
  &:hover {
    li {
      opacity: 0.4;
    }
  }
  li {
    transition: opacity .8s;
    &:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/jonathandion/pen/XRYKNY)